# Constructor setting all values to 0

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, private

So from an assignment I have from school, I have to make a default constructor that is supposed to set all floats and ints to 0 and all strings to "NA".

Earlier it was pretty easy I had to just do a constructor to set volume to 0, calories to 0 and etc.

My question is,

How does the syntax for setting all floats, and ints to 0 and trying to get strings to all say "NA"?

This is what I had so far

```
class Candy {
private:
    float sweetness;

protected:
    string color;

//CONSTRUCTOR//

    void setName(string n);

    void setFloat(float f);

    void setInt(int i);
```

This is on another cpp file we have to do.

```
Candy::Candy() {

Candy(string n) {
    setName(n);
}

Candy bo("NA");
}
```

Am I in the right direction? I am really new to this, and I am not very good with syntax. Thanks!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list That comment is lying, BTW.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the constructors initialization list:

```
class Candy {
private:
    float sweetness;

protected:
    string color;

public:
    Candy() : sweetness(0.0f), color("NA") { }
};
```

Or (in C++11 or later), use in-class initializers:

```
class Candy {
private:
    float sweetness = 0.0f;

protected:
    string color = "NA";

public:
    Candy() = default;
};
```

Comment: The second approach is not applicable for C++ standards prior to C++ 11. The OP should be aware of this.

Comment: @duong_dajgja The question is tagged both c++11 and c++14, so feel it's safe to assume we are not in pre-C++11 land ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl No, the question is not tagged with any specific version, so mentioning in which version this works would be a good addition to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets see your header file:

```
class Candy {
public:
    Candy();
private:
    float sweetness;

protected:
    string color;

    void setName(string n);

    void setFloat(float f);

    void setInt(int i);
};
```

You need to declare the constructor in the public section, so you can call it from outside. It has no return type and takes no parameters (it should set everything to 0 on its own and not values you provide it).

In the cpp-file you implement the constructor and the other methods you declared before:

```
#include "Candy.h" // Or whatever the filename is

Candy::Candy() {
    sweetness = 0.0f;
    color = "NA";
}

// Implement the other methods, I don't know what they should do
// Example:
void Candy::setName(string n) {
    // Do what you want
}
```

Note you have to implement every method otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: So if I had to set all floats or intergers to 0 I would just say

"floats = 0;"?

Comment: You really should prefer using the constructors initialization list rather than the constructor body. Using the body means members are first default initialized and then subsequently assigned to. That's inefficient (and for some types even impossible).

Comment: @PKPython there is no such thing as "setting all floats to zero" like `floats = 0;`. You need to set them to zero (or whatever othe value) individually. The most upvoted answer is what you need.